# What does fillViewPort in scrollView really do?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, viewport

What is the benefit of `fillViewPort`?

In `ScrollView`, sometimes `fillViewPort` needs to be set to `true` so that the view gets displayed properly, and other times it's not needed at all.

And the documentations' description of it is not really clear

> android:fillViewport
>
> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`fillViewport` allows `scrollView` to extend it’s height equals to the full height of device screen’s height in the cases when the child of scroll view has less height.

Thank for Hardik Parsania for [this](https://demonuts.com/android-fillviewport/) helpful post

Answer (score 15):

Source of this sample : [demonuts.com](https://demonuts.com/android-fillviewport/)

**`fillViewport = “false”`**

[image]

---

**`fillViewport = “true”`**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`fillViewport = true` is advised for `scrollView`s containing a `recyclerView` that implements padding in the direction of the scroll (i.e. `paddingBottom` and/or `paddingTop` for vertical scrolling). Doing so, when paired with `clipToPadding = false` for the `recyclerView`, negates shrinkage of the viewport on scrolling to the point at which the `recyclerView` padding enters view.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#:~:text=Never%20add%20a%20RecyclerView%20or%20ListView%20to%20a%20scroll%20view.%20Doing%20so%20results%20in%20poor%20user%20interface%20performance%20and%20a%20poor%20user%20experience.), its not advised to have a recycler view inside a scroll view - `Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.`