# How to set height of one layout to the height of another layout in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, binding

I have this code. So I want to set height in my relativeLayout by height in scrollView. Can I set height by id of scrollView? It's need, because I have many fragments, but one of them should take height of scrollView (when virtual keyboard is open).

```
...
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frameViewer"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/layoutViewer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
              <WebView
                       android:id="@+id/webViewer"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent">
          </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView`s child (and its childrens also) should have set `layout_height="wrap_content"` for avoiding multiple re-measurements (way better performance)

if you want to fullfil whole `ScrollView` even when content have less height then use [`fillViewport` xml attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588392/what-does-fillviewport-in-scrollview-really-do)

Comment: Oh, I thought it's not important,  sorry)) I already have fillViewport. But I can't make my relativeLayout wrap_content,  because I have a webView inside 

Comment: well, `WebView` is scrollable by itself, so it shoudn't be placed inside another scrollable `View` (the solution may be to use nested scrolling pattern). btw. when `WebView` have `match_parent` height and placed inside some other scrollable container then it will draw whole web page - if this page have some scroll-to-end detection (e.g. by JS) or some divs sticked to the bottom then these features won't work properly (fire at start, divs on the bottom of page, not viewport, etc.)...