# Show one item at screen in a static scroll view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, scroll

I want to create just the front-end of an android app which can show the working of a scroll view in a way that scroll view shows only one layout or one item at a time ( For eg. in Instagram application moving from one post to another) which means there is only one complete post on the screen at a time rather than two half post when you just swipe up once.

Also it's just static data and no use of recycler view or adapter in background so have to work with scroll view option or any other alternative if you know.

activity_main.xml

```
  <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView"

  >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <include layout="@layout/layout_text_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_image_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_text_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_image_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_text_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_image_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_text_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_image_feed" />

  <include layout="@layout/layout_text_feed" />
</LinearLayout>
```

These are two types of layout files one having just text and other having image and are just randomly arranged to give a prototype of a feed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try to add this add attribute  to your ScrollView       android:fillViewport="true"

You can get brief answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588993/9328761)

Thank for Hardik Parsania for [this](https://demonuts.com/android-fillviewport/) helpful post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).