# My ViewPager2 height (android:layout_height="0dp") is not covering the parent and filling the available space, when i put it in scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview, android-viewpager2

here i have a *ViewPager inside the scroll view its 'layout_height' is 0dp*

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR**  : The viewPager should have covered the remaining screen

**REAL BEHAVIOUR** : The viewPager height gets wrapped due to which my textview in fragment is not getting displayed

The reason behind this I think is the constrain layout inside scroll view , for some reason its layout-height gets wrap_content , may be its because , its inside the scroll view ,

can someone help me and make the viewPager cover remaing screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20mdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30mdp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
            android:text="My\nNotes"
            android:textColor="@color/brand_color"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_230mdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20mdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30mdp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
            app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/brand_color"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30mdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I have tried adding nested scroll view , then added linear layout instead constrain , buts nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the Scrollview and also set the height of the child ConstraintLayout to 0dp.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
            android:text="My\nNotes"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But, I don't understand why you need 2 ConstraintLayout. This xml can be made simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView should solve this issue.

```
<ScrollView 
...
    android:fillViewport="true"
...>
```

Whenever you use ScrollView or NestedScrollView, its height will be wrap content. `fillViewport` allows scrollView to extend it’s height equals to the full height of device screen’s height in the cases when the child of scroll view has less height.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56588392/8192914) thread for more.